# What is the difference between Web App Bot and Azure Bot

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, botframework, azure-bot-service

[image: screenshot]

Bot Framework SDK documentation says that Web App Bot is deprecated. But there is no information  about the difference between development with Azure Bot and (deprecated) Web App Bot. What exact changes should be done if we migrate form one service (Web App Bot) to another (Azure Bot)?

Comment: Instead of posting a screenshot, consider posting the link and add a quote with the relevant text.

Comment: I second this question. I still create web app bots via a workaound (QnaMaker) because there is no clear explanation for developers used to creating web app bots and are now forced to use azure bots.

Answer (score 2):

> In regards of other contributor's answer, I think main concept and
> queries has not explained accordingly, so I felt it requires more
> explanation in addition to clear the OP's main concern.

***`Questions:`*** `But there is no information about the difference between development with Azure Bot and (deprecated) Web App Bot.`

> The Bot Service behind `Azure Bot` and `Web App Bot/Bot Channels Registration` is the same; the change is in how the resources are
> created that you use in your bot such as web apps, language
> understanding, and more.
>
> Rather than the one size fits all templates that the `Web App Bot` used,
> `Bot Framework Composer` can be used to create resources for the Bot
> with much more flexibility than the `Web App Bot` templates allowed.
>
> `Bot Channels Registration` and `Azure Bot` are basically the same
> capabilities renamed. The UX is slightly different in the Azure Portal
> to help customers connect to the Bot Framework Composer.

*Its clearly documented here in the official document [`you can get here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-resources-faq-azure?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#what-s-the-difference-between-the-azure-bot-and-the-web-app-bot-or-bot-channels-registration)*

***`Questions:`*** `What exact changes should be done if we migrate form one service (Web App Bot) to another (Azure Bot)?`

> [`Currently migration from` Web App Bot`to`Azure Bot `isn't supported.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-resources-faq-azure?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#can-i-migrate-my-existing-bot-resource-to-an-azure-bot)
> If your `Web App Bot` isn't being used in production, you can delete
> your old `Web App Bot` resource and reuse the bot name and app ID in a
> new bot resource (after some time for the old record to get deleted).
> The new `Azure Bot` is designed around creating your bot using
> Composer, `Bot Framework SDK`, and so the gains from such a migration
> would be minimal. You can get the [`official explanation here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-resources-faq-azure?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#can-i-migrate-my-existing-bot-resource-to-an-azure-bot)

***`Note:`***

Now you might be wondering, what about your existing `Web app bot`. Your bot and other resources will continue to work without any problem and you don't need to migrate your `old web app bot` in this aspect.

***`One question may arise,then why its been depricated or no longer be used`?***

> The answer would be, Functionally though Azure Bot, Web App Bot, and
> Bot Channels Registration all utilize the Bot Service in the same way
> "under the hood". The `Azure Bot` path is easier, and more
> configurable for developers in comparison of `Web app bot`

Hope above explanation will redeem your concern.

Answer (score 0):

The [Azure Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/abs-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned) is like the Bot Channel Registration. It is a global resource that identifies your bot to toher Azure resources and contains configurations and settings for the bot's external messaging endpoint, channels (Teams, Web Chat, Email, etc.), Exposing APIs, OAuth settings, and more.

To actually host the bot, you would use an Azure App Service. You would create one during the [deployment process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp%2Cuserassigned).

As the stated in the linked docs, existing resources will continue to work. Note that the docs specify that [migration is not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-resources-faq-azure?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#can-i-migrate-my-existing-bot-resource-to-an-azure-bot). Moving forward, when you build a new bot, you should use a combination of an Azure Bot for identity and configuration and an App Service to host and run the bot.